# Need one aggregation query to do $match, $group and return count of matching elements and count of all elements in each group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection as follows:
    {color:'blue', category:'A', .....}
    {color:'yellow', category:'A',....}
    {color:'blue', category:'B',......}
    ...
    ....

A query like:
    db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{color:'blue'}}, {$group:{_id:"$category", num:{$sum:1}}}])

returns Number of documents with color:'blue' for each category.

Now, I want to also get the total number of documents in each category - in the same aggregation query.  This is so as to avoid an extra query to the mongodb server on a very large database.  As it is the first query takes more than a few minutes to complete.  Adding another query will almost duplicate the work for the database server (grouping and counting again) and therefore take much longer.
Is this possible?

If not, is there a single API call to merge two AggregationOutput results on a specified key field?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just group category as you've done (without the `$match`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$category", 
                     num:{$sum:1}, 
                     blues:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$color","blue"]}, 1, 0]}}
}}]
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a minor correction:  ["color":"blue"] should actually be coded as ["color", "blue"].

Comment: Is the following correct?  ............{$eq:["$attributes.color","red"]}.............. in a situation where "attributes" is an array of subdocuments....and, "color" is a field in the subdocument.  Problem is that the related $sum is 0 (I presume that is because the $cond evaluates to 0 for each document.)

Comment: if it's an array you need to add {$unwind:"$attributes"} before group...  the problem here is that you will over match so you will need to add {$match:{"attribute.color":{$exists:true}} or something like that to keep only one of each object...

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea.